# Custom Google Now commands

Tags: java, android, google-now, google-voice-search

How can I intercept Google Now voice commands?

I want that for example my app say Google Now "If the query contains xy send me an intent". How can I do that?

I found this (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Now) but it was not verry helpful.

Comment: AFAIK what you want is not possible, the only thing you can do to search your app is this http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/the-fastest-route-between-voice-search.html

Comment: But other apps like Tasker and Commandr do the same.

Comment: its not exactly user friendly http://lifehacker.com/how-to-create-custom-voice-commands-with-tasker-and-aut-1282209195

Comment: Well, I want that the user should be able to use this function from my app without downloading any other apps.

Comment: and like I said there is no way to do that

Comment: @tyczj A way to intercept the search text from Google Now exists for sure, as **AutoVoice** application is using it (without root). It involves creating an accessibility service, but unfortunately I'm unable to find any documentation about that.